# WordPress Multisite Non-www Redirects All Point to Home Page

Tags: wordpress, redirect

All non-www pages of my WordPress site redirect to the www version of the home page. I've tested multiple WordPress themes to rule out my theme and the same issue occurs. It also occurs on other sites within the multisite installation.

Here is my WordPress .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN NON-WWW REDIRECT TO WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
# END NON-WWW REDIRECT TO WWW
```

The site is WordPress 4. I thought WordPress itself should automatically do the non-www redirect out of the box if it has the domain setup. Do you have ideas as to what is causing the issue or ways to diagnose?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That had no effect for the issue above. I'd also be careful using what you have as all subdomains would also redirect to their www version.